# listen for key event while swing main thread is running

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jframe, jfilechooser

I have a swing application which takes user input and goes to full screen and displays variations of input image, I want to stop this thread execution on particular key press (prig should not terminate) and program should ask for the another user input. don't know how to approach? plz help here's code:::

```
public class ImageProcessor extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 2916361361443483318L;
private JFileChooser fc = null;
private JMenuItem item1, item2;
private BufferedImage image = null;
private JFrame frame = null;
private JPanel panel = null;
private int width = 0;
private int height = 0;
private BorderLayout card;
private Container contentPane;
private int wcount = 0;
private int hcount = 0;

public ImageProcessor() {


    frame = new JFrame("Image Processor");
    contentPane = frame.getContentPane();

    panel = new JPanel();
    card = new BorderLayout();
    panel.setLayout(card);
    panel.setBackground(Color.white);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu");
    menu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_M);
    menuBar.add(menu);

    item1 = new JMenuItem("Browse an image");
    item2 = new JMenuItem("Exit");

    item1.addActionListener(this);
    item2.addActionListener(this);

    menu.add(item1);
    menu.add(item2);

    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    contentPane.add(panel);
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new ImageProcessor();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (e.getSource() == item1) {
        if (fc == null)
            fc = new JFileChooser();
        int retVal = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (retVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
            try {
                image = ImageIO.read(file);
                width = image.getWidth();
                height = image.getHeight();

                final GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
                frame.getJMenuBar().setVisible(false);
                gd.setFullScreenWindow(frame);


                Timer timer = new Timer(0, new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        panel.removeAll();
                        //System.out.println(wcount + " " + hcount);
                        if(wcount <= width-1 && hcount <= height-1){
                            Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(wcount, hcount));
                            panel.setBackground(c);
                            panel.revalidate();
                            panel.repaint();
                        }
                        ((Timer)e.getSource()).setDelay(333);
                        if(wcount <= width-1){
                            if(hcount < height-1 )
                                hcount++;
                            else{
                                hcount = 0;
                                wcount++;
                            }
                        }else{
                            //((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
                            //gd.setFullScreenWindow(null);
                            //frame.getJMenuBar().setVisible(true);
                            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Image Read Complete!");
                            wcount = 0;
                            hcount = 0;
                        }
                    }
                });

                timer.start();

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                System.out.println("IO::" + e1.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                System.out.println("Exception::" + e1.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    if (e.getSource() == item2) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

}

plz advice..

Comment: Have you looked at the [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)?

Comment: my question is not about the key listener. how to listen for the key evens while your main thread is doing some task?

Comment: thread starting from main method

Comment: The problem is, the Event Dispatching Thread, which is the main UI thread, is responsible for handling all, well, event dispatching, so you would need some kind of component listening for and processing the key events and then passing those of to "other" thread